# Can't hide titlebar Titanium with Alloy

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I have encounterd a problem in Titanium Appcelerator using Alloy MVC. This problem contains the following(see image)

[image]

I can't remove the black bar where the app name and logo is found. I am running the app on a device(Google Nexus, no simulator)

I have tried the following to remove this:

XML:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

TSS:

```
"Window":
{
    navBarHidden:true,
    fullscreen:true,
    backgroundColor:"Orange",
    orientationModes:[Ti.UI.PORTRAIT],
}
```

TiApp.XML:

```
<statusbar-style>default</statusbar-style>
<statusbar-hidden>true</statusbar-hidden>
<fullscreen>true</fullscreen>
<navbar-hidden>true</navbar-hidden>
```

But none of these options are working to hide this black bar. In the iOS simulator it does remove the navigation bar by only setting the property `fullscreen` to true

Are there other options to get this away? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it the ActionBar that's showing perhaps? Try hiding it.

> To modify the theme to hide the action bar:
>
> 1. Add a custom theme file to your project:
>
> platform/android/res/values/custom_theme.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources>
    <style name="Theme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.Titanium">
        <!-- Depending on the parent theme, this may be called android:windowActionBar instead of windowActionBar -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style> </resources>
```

Taken from: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Action_Bar

Comment: use @Protossoario's answer

Answer (score 13):

If you're using Titanium SDK 3.3.0, the Titanium theme, which is one of the default themes, now hides the action and status bar. To use it, just add this to your tiapp.xml.

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

You can read more about this and other themes that Titanium has for Android here: [Android Themes](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Themes).

Answer (score 1):

I just added the code below in my TiApp.xml to hide the action bar that is where the name of my app and logo of Titanium were

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
    <application android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium"/>
</manifest>
```

You can hide the status bar too (where the clock, battery level, notifications, etc. are) by adding the statusbar line

```
<fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
<statusbar-hidden>true</statusbar-hidden>
<analytics>true</analytics>
```