# Titanium: Tabgroup navbar

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

How do i get rid of that (marked in pink):

[image: Titanium bar of somes ort]

I dont see it anywhere in the code?

Code:

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');
var tabgroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup({top:0, tabsAtBottom: true})
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor:'#393A3A',
    navBarHidden: true
});
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    icon:'images/ic_search.png',
    title:'Tab 1',
    window:win1
});
var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 2',
    backgroundColor:'#393A3A',
    navBarHidden: true
});
var tab2 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    icon:'images/ic_news.png',
    title:'Tab 2',
    window:win2
});

tabgroup.addTab(tab1);  
tabgroup.addTab(tab2);  
tabgroup.open();
```

Comment: http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/08/hiding-the-android-actionbar/

Answer (score 0):

you can change the value of tags or combination of tags

```
<statusbar-hidden>true</statusbar-hidden>
<fullscreen>true</fullscreen>
<navbar-hidden>true</navbar-hidden>
```

to `true` in your `tiapp.xml` file.  Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

before 3.3.0 sdk released, you can use navBarHidden property of window or tab group to hide that bar but after 3.3.0 sdk, you need to use actionBar to hide that bar.

And to do that you need to use current activity to hide actionBar

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25693786/117701
I added the xml to my manifest file, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Set tabgroup's title to ""

var tabgroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup({top:0, tabsAtBottom: true, **title: ""**});